# Exception in trigger, fail to update the field on account which is used to count the number of contact with specific type

Tags: after-trigger

Please help me out.
I posted my trigger please it throws the exception

> Exception Details: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   0035000003IGI8AAAX; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   ContactTrainerCountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable: The record you
>   are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is currently
>   being modified by another user. Please try again.

My trigger named "`ConactTrainerCountTrigger`" and the trigger code is given below:

```
trigger ContactTrainerCountTrigger on Contact (After insert, After delete, After undelete, After Update) {
    Set<Id> parentIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
    List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    IF(Trigger.IsAfter){
        IF(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUndelete){
            FOR(Contact c : Trigger.new){
                if(c.AccountId!=null){   
                    parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId);

                }
            }
            System.debug('parentIdsSet' + parentIdsSet);
        }
        IF(Trigger.IsUpdate){
            FOR(Contact c : Trigger.new){
                if(c.AccountId!=null){
                    if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Type__c != c.Type__c || Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId != c.AccountId){
                        parentIdsSet.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId);
                        parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        IF(Trigger.IsDelete){
            FOR(Contact c : Trigger.Old){
                if(c.AccountId!=null){   
                    parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId); 
                }
            }
        }


        List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>([Select id ,Name,Trainer_Count__c, (Select id, Name From Contacts where Type__c = 'Trainer') from Account Where id in:parentIdsSet for Update]);
        System.debug('accountList' + accountList);
        FOR(Account acc : accountList){
            System.debug('acc' +acc);
            List<Contact> contactList = acc.Contacts;
            acc.Trainer_Count__c = contactList.size();
            accountListToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
        update accountListToUpdate;

    }

}
```

Comment: Issue seems to be with After Update event, there must be another process/user firing up after update and trying to update the same record.

Answer (score 0):

I executed this trigger on my org and I found no problems:

```
trigger ContactTrainerCountTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {


Set<Id> parentIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();

if (Trigger.isAfter) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete) {
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
            if (c.AccountId != null) {
                parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId);

            }
        }
        System.debug('parentIdsSet' + parentIdsSet);
    }

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
            if (c.AccountId != null) {
                if (Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Type__c != c.Type__c || Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId != c.AccountId) {
                    parentIdsSet.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId);
                    parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Contact c : Trigger.old) {
            if (c.AccountId != null) {
                parentIdsSet.add(c.AccountId);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>([
            SELECT Id,Name,Trainer_Count__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts WHERE Type__c = 'Trainer')
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN :parentIdsSet
            FOR UPDATE
    ]);
    System.debug('accountList' + accountList);

    for (Account acc : accountList) {
        System.debug('acc' + acc);
        List<Contact> contactList = acc.Contacts;
        acc.Trainer_Count__c = contactList.size();
        accountListToUpdate.add(acc);
    }
    if (!accountListToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update accountListToUpdate;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I got the correct amount on my accounts every time the logic was met:

**Account 1:**

[image]

**Account 2:**

[image]

The one reason I can think of is other operation running on the accounts you want to update.

I think you can use `Database.SaverResult` here and then alert of any issues or even fire the changes to those records that were blocked latter.

```
 if (!accountListToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(accountListToUpdate, false);
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Records successfully updated: ' + sr.getId());
                } else {
                    for (Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');
                        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is going to make sure that if you are facing issues with some accounts the operation is not failing because one record. Salesforce uses [Collision Detection](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Summer07:_Update_Collision_Detection) which should be able to stop updating a record at the same time from two different points, this is on the UI.

You can process the failing record/s in a different way after you catch them.